# Retrofit VBA code so it can loop through columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this bit of code in my VBA tinkering for years:

```
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
    ""
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I now need to be able to take this function, and loop it through 1460 columns, but that 1460 will be variable.

My tries so far look like this:

```
Dim a As Interger
a = 3

Do While Cells(1, a) <> ""

    Range(Range("R1Ca:RCa") & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
        "[super convoluted formula]"
    Range(Range("R1Ca:RCa") & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

    a = a + 1

Loop
```

So my focused question at this point is how do I modify the "B2:B" in my starting example into a variable that can be looped to hit all of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to calculate the "last row" once, e.g.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

That then allows your current statement of

```
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula =
```

to be replaced by the equivalent

```
Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Formula =
```

which can be re-expressed, using `Cells` instead of addresses, as

```
Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(lastRow, "B")).Formula =
```

This can then be easily converted to a formula which uses a variable for the column:

```
Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lastRow, c)).Formula =
```

Note that the column parameter of the `Cells` object can be either expressed as a number (i.e. column 1, 2, 3, etc) or as a string (i.e. column "A", "B", "C", etc).  Using a numeric value is useful when iterating over multiple columns.  Using a string value is useful when you are just using a single, known, column - it makes the code more "readable".

---

Your rewritten code could therefore be:

```
Dim c As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For c = 2 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lastRow, c)).Formula = "[super convoluted formula]"
    Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lastRow, c)).Value = _
             Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lastRow, c)).Value
Next
```

(There is no need to do a copy/paste if you are just trying to paste values - it will be safer to just set the `Value` property to the `Value` property.)